# Splitting error- IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, split

I got stuck with an issue, that I can't seem to solve. When splitting I should be able to get *id, name, check* by setting *row[0], row[1], row[2]*. Strangely only row[0] (id) seem to work. *Name, check* gives me an error. Could someone help me further?

**Example of data:**

```
id,name,check
1,john,0
1,patrick,0
1,naruto,0
```

**Code:**

```
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(openFileInput(listLocation(listLoc)));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
             String[] row = line.split(Pattern.quote(","));
                 //names.add(row[0]); // id
                 names.add(row[1]); // name // ERROR AT THIS LINE
                 //names.add(row[2]); // check
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Error message:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

**Solved**
It seems I had an incorrect value (question marks) at end of file. When removing this line.  My code worked (without Patter.quote). Thank you all for fast reply's. First answer helped me on reminding me of using Log value where I could see the 'incorrect value'. My bad.

Comment: what does `Pattern.quote(",")` return ? and what is your input String

Comment: Only possible error seems is, read **line** does not have ',' in it.

Print **line** before processing and verify it has correct data

Comment: Simply use: `String[] row = line.split(",");` Since `Pattern.quote` won't split anything, and you'll get the full, **unsplitted** line. (which will result in **length = 1**, instead of the expected **lenght = 3**)

Comment: The comma doesn't have any particular meaning in a regex, so shouldn't need to pass through any `Pattern.quote()`. Are you sure of the contents of the string you're reading? Is the comma really the seperating value? If you print out the line read, is it correct?

Comment: String regularExp="(\\d+)(,)([^,]*)(,)(\\d+)"; 
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regualrExp,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
 Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String id =m.group(1);
        String comma1=m.group(2);
        String name=m.group(3);
        String comma2=m.group(4);
 String check = m.group(5);
   }

Comment: When I set **line**. It returns as expected: 1,john,0

Comment: I changed it back to line.split(","). Getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably in the time:

```
String[] row = line.split(",");
```

was called, there was no comma (,) in the line of the file/stream you're trying to read.

Comment: Yes, there are probably blank lines at the end of the file

Comment: Cyto, I think you're looking to wrong direction.

Try to look at br.readLine() first and see if every time it's called, it returns a string that contains a comma.

Comment: Interesting. I logged br.readline(). It works when I add: Log.d("name", br.readLine()); at end of loop. oO

Comment: I posted one better approach. See it below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(openFileInput(listLocation(listLoc)));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] row = line.split(",");
            //names.add(row[0]); // id
            names.add(row[1]); // name // ERROR AT THIS LINE
            //names.add(row[2]); // check
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I think you don't need to use `Pattern.quote(",")` here.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with txt files this is the best way of dealing with it:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Cyto {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            FileInputStream dis = new FileInputStream("list.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
            String line;
            while (br.ready()) {
                line = br.readLine();
                String[] row = line.split(Pattern.quote(","));      
                System.out.println(row[1]);
                names.add(row[1]);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Use

```
br.ready()
```

instead of reading directly from stream.

Comment: Thx, I'm using br.ready(). @FileInputStream I get an error *open failed: no such file or directory* My approach (DataInputStream) works dunno if its better.

Comment: I adapted your code to mine, as I don't know how is your directory / files structure.